# Create a table with select columns from Another Table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm trying to break down a GPS point in a new table since the old table is in CHAR my new table will be set to INT.

```
Drop Table LoopTest1;

CREATE TABLE LoopTest1 (
`Account Number`  char(32) NULL ,
`Latitude`  decimal(30,2) NULL ,
`LatDegree`  int(2) NULL ,
`LatMinutes`  int(2) NULL ,
`LatSeconds`  decimal(5,2) NULL ,
`LatDecimal`  decimal(30,6) NULL ,
`Longitude`  decimal(30,2) NULL ,
`LongDegree`  int(2) NULL ,
`LongMinutes`  int(2) NULL ,
`LongSeconds`  decimal(5,2) NULL ,
`LongDecimal`  decimal(30,6) NULL 
);

set 
        LoopTest2.`Account Number` = LoopTest1.`Account Number`,
        LoopTest2.Latitude = LoopTest1.Latitude,
        LoopTest2.Longitude =LoopTest1. Longitude

FROM
        LoopTest2
```

This will only be a temp table since I will update LoopTest2 with the changes made in LoopTest1

Comment: Question is not clear, please try clarify.

Comment: I keep getting errors, I'm trying to create this Temp Table called LoopTest1, Pulling only 3 columns from my main table LoopTest2.  After I get the 3 columns pulled I can break it down even more inside of the temp table.  Once I get it broke down and put back together in the Temp table I will update the main table (LoopTest2) with the new data